# python graphing the 1D wave equation (Beginner)

Tags: python, animation, numpy, matplotlib, waveform

I literally just started learning how to code in Python. I am interested

1. How to reproduce `u[x,t]` matrix. I tried `return u` and it throws me an error.
2. If the placement of `for` loops in this code correct and runs properly.
3. Most importantly, How can I animate this 1D wave eqaution where I can see how the wave evolves from a gaussian and split into two waves of the same height.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dx=0.1 #space increment
dt=0.05 #time increment
tmin=0.0 #initial time
tmax=2.0 #simulate until
xmin=-5.0 #left bound
xmax=5.0 #right bound...assume packet never reaches boundary
c=1.0 #speed of sound
rsq=(c*dt/dx)**2 #appears in finite diff sol

nx = int((xmax-xmin)/dx) + 1 #number of points on x grid
nt = int((tmax-tmin)/dt) + 2 #number of points on t grid
u = np.zeros((nt,nx)) #solution to WE

#set initial pulse shape
def init_fn(x):
    val = np.exp(-(x**2)/0.25)
    if val<.001:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return val

for a in range(0,nx):
    u[0,a]=init_fn(xmin+a*dx)
    u[1,a]=u[0,a]

#simulate dynamics
for t in range(1,nt-1):
    for a in range(1,nx-1):
        u[t+1,a] = 2*(1-rsq)*u[t,a]-u[t-1,a]+rsq*(u[t,a-1]+u[t,a+1])


# Where is the code that is needed to run the simulation?
```

There were some animation codes I saw that were too complicated for me to understand. Could anyone help me with the problems that I addressed above? Thank You!

Comment: Not directly about your question, but a note about Python: you shouldn't put semicolons at the end of lines of code in Python. Although they're technically permissible, they're completely redundant and what's more, make it harder to read since a semicolon at the end of a line (which signifies nothing) looks like a colon at the end of a line (which would indicate that the following code is part of an inner block.) I've already edited your code to remove those unnecessary semicolons and I also made other small changes to clean up your code.

Comment: I'm not sure if `numpy` comes with graphical libraries or not (I've never used it, personally). It probably does, but if it doesn't, you may need to use `Tkinter`: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of your file do:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plts = []             # get ready to populate this list the Line artists to be plotted
plt.hold("off")
for i in range(nt):
    p, = plt.plot(u[i,:], 'k')   # this is how you'd plot a single line...
    plts.append( [p] )           # ... but save the line artist for the animation
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, plts, interval=50, repeat_delay=3000)   # run the animation
ani.save('wave.mp4')    # optionally save it to a file

plt.show()
```

Here's a gif of the mp4:

[image]

Comment: What does the function def init_fn(x):,please? It is initial conditions? How is the equation integrated?

Comment: @Alex: The function `init_fx` is a single bump centered at x=0. The specific form of the bump, `exp(-x**2/s)` is often called a Gaussian or bell curve.